# index out of bounds because numel ()

Tags: matlab

I want to check each of the `age` from a file named "2".  This "2" file contains ages and is formatted in the following way:

- 2010
- 1997
- 0
- ...
- ...

The code I have written to do this is below, but it returns an error:

[image]

```
data_register = importdata('DATA/2')

for i = 1:700

year=data_register(i);

age=2014-year(i);

B22(A22<=1)=1;
B22(A22>1&A22<50)=-1;
B22(A22>=50)=1; 


D22(i)=B22';

end

feature22= D22'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why is because `year` is only a single element.  When you move to the next iteration, you are traversing out of bounds as `year` is just a single element but you are trying to access the non-existent second element.

The reason why `year` is a single element is due to the `year = data_register(i)` assignment.  You need to change the `age` assignment to the following:

```
age = 2014 - year;
```

### Aside

Your `for` loop doesn't make any sense to me.  I'm not sure why you are using `age` when you aren't using it in the statements that follow it.  What is `A22`? `B22`?  Is it related to `age`?  How are these being calculated?

Comment: i get the error like "??? Attempted to access
data_register(699); index out of
bounds because
numel(data_register)=698.

Error in ==> f22 at 6
   year=data_register(i);"

Comment: That's because you only have `698` elements in `data_register`.  You need to change the `for` loop so that it only goes up to `698`.  One way to fix this is to not rely on a static number but to check how long the array is.  Fix the `for` loop so that it is `for i = 1 : length(data_register)` instead.

Comment: no, i have 700 data, while i have set 1:700 in for loop, no idea while it stop when i =699

Comment: Not according to that MATLAB error.  It says you have `698` elements in the array.  BTW I'm going to downvote as it doesn't seem like you know what you're doing.

Comment: but i really have 700 data, i have recreate the file, it still the same

Comment: That I can't help you fix because you haven't given me enough to work with.  However, you can make it work better by making the end index of the loop to be assigned to `length(data_register)`.  You should either check your file to see if there is 700 elements, or check your `importdata` function and see if you are missing anything from there.

Comment: Clearly you do not have 700 data points, or else MATLAB would not give the error! It is also possible that MATLAB is importing your data file improperly. You should check this...

Comment: @user3340270: BTW, you should consider vectorizing that code.  From what it looks like, you don't even need a `for` loop.

Comment: Check my edited post.  There are a couple of things that don't make any sense to me, and perhaps this will help you fix further errors along the road.